# :after div is hidden (cut) in ipad

Tags: html, css

:after selector div is not exceeding from the orignal div and appears cut. 
for some reason the div is cut on ipad but the browser view is fine.

Browser display on the left and actual device display on the right. 
see pic:

[image: browser display on the left vs actual display on ipad device]

Here is the css code:

```
    .validationWrapper .ui-dialog-titlebar.ui-corner-all {
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #f86161;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e04343;
}

.validationWrapper {
    font-size: 14px !important;
    font-weight: 800 !important;
    max-width: 450px;
    height: 250px !important;
    top: 46% !important;
    right: 8.2% !important;
    left: auto !important;
    background: #fff !important;
}

    .validationWrapper:after {
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
        position: fixed;
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        top: 48%;
        z-index: 1;
        right: 7.85%;
        background-color: #f86161;
        content: "";
        box-shadow: -1px -1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    }

@media (max-width: 768px) {

    body.ios7 .validationWrapper {
        max-width: 441px !important;
        height: 250px !important;
        top: 16% !important;
        right: 20.2% !important;
        left: auto !important;
    }

        body.ios7 .validationWrapper:after {
            background-color: #f86161;
            top: 161px;
            left: 26%;
        }
}
```

Comment: Why are you sharing the media-query code? Give us the main styles.

Comment: @Sqnkov I have updated the question

Comment: Provide HTML too please.

Answer (score 0):

From what I am seeing at first sight:

- You should apply a `position: relative` to your `.validationWrapper` object.
- You should change the position of `.validationWrapper:after` from `fixed` to `absolute`

Using `position: fixed` for you pseudo element is not a good practice, because it will only display that element in a specific position in the window, and will not be scalable/movable.

Like so:

```
.validationWrapper {
    position: relative; /* <=== New rule */
    font-size: 14px !important;
    font-weight: 800 !important;
    max-width: 450px;
    height: 250px !important;
    top: 46% !important;
    right: 8.2% !important;
    left: auto !important;
    background: #fff !important;
}

.validationWrapper:after {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    position: absolute; /* <=== New Rule */
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 48%;
    z-index: 1;
    right: 7.85%;
    background-color: #f86161;
    content: "";
    box-shadow: -1px -1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
```

And, after that You should align the pseudo element (`:after`) to fit its new position needs.